# Storing the first word in each line of a string into a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a string containing multiple lines. Each line is broken by '\n' and contains commas after each word. I want to store the first word in each line into a list.

Here is the string output:

```
AIG,10,,,,Yes,,,Jr,,,MS,,
Baylor College of Medicine,19,Yes,Yes,,,,,,,,,,Recent
CGG,17,Yes,Yes,,,,,,,,MS,PhD,Recent
Citi,27/28,Yes,,,Yes,,,Jr,Sr,,,,
```

My list should be `['AIG', 'Baylor College of Medicine', 'CGG', 'Citi']`

I thought about using split after the first comma and then go to the next line, but I do not know how I can achieve this.

---

**My Solution was to go back in my code and search for a list of "companies" I previously made.**

**companies =**

`['AIG,10,,,,Yes,,,Jr,,,MS,,\n', 'Baylor\xa0College\xa0of\xa0Medicine,19,Yes,Yes,,,,,,,,,,Recent\n', 'CGG,17,Yes,Yes,,,,,,,,MS,PhD,Recent\n', 'Citi,27/28,Yes,,,Yes,,,Jr,Sr,,,,\n', 'ExxonMobil,11,Yes,,,Yes,Fr,Soph,Jr,Sr,PB,,,\n', 'Flow-Cal\xa0Inc.,16,Yes,,,Yes,,,Jr,Sr,,,,All\n', 'Global\xa0Shop\xa0Solutions,18,Yes,,,Yes,,,,Sr,PB,,,All\n']`

```
cmpny_name = []
for i  in companies:
    cmpny_name.append(i.split(',', 1)[0])

cmpny_name = [c.replace('\xa0', ' ') for c in cmpny_name]
print(cmpny_name)

OUTPUT:['AIG', 'Baylor College of Medicine', 'CGG', 'Citi', 'ExxonMobil', 'Flow-Cal Inc.', 'Global Shop Solutions', 'Harris County CTS', 'HCSS', 'Hitachi Consulting', 'HP Inc.', 'INT Inc.']
```

Comment: It looks like you trying to process a csv file. did you check the csv module? you could also use `str.partition` to do this

Comment: @styvane correct this is from a csv file. First time working with a csv file in python. I looked at the csv module and couldn't find anything helpful for my skill level. I have, however, found a solution that works,but uses split.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use `split` two times:

```
lines = string.split('\n')
output = [line.split(',')[0] for line in lines]
```

Comment: You shouldn't use `split`. It better to use `str.partition` if you don't want to use the csv module

Comment: OK, I didn't know about `str.partition`

Comment: You can also do `str.split(',', 1)[0]`, which should have about the same performance as `str.partition`

Comment: @styvane can you explain why we should prefer `output = [line.partition(',')[0] for line in lines` over `output = [line.split(',')[0] for line in lines]`? Or did I misunderstand the usage of `str.partition`?

Comment: @Aemyl Since you only need to split the string once, performance is technically better with `str.partition`.  For relatively short lines in short files, the difference won't be that noticeable.

Comment: @BrendanAbel oh, ok. My first thought was it could be safer since the output length is always 3 which reduces the risk of index out of range exceptions, but performance is still a good reason (especially if it is nOT less readable)

Answer (score 3):

I wold slightly simplify @Amely's answer

```
from pprint import pprint
a="this is line 1\nthat is line 2\nthose are line3\nbill was here\nbob was here"
first = [line.split(' ')[0] for line in a.split('\n')]
pprint(first)
```

And you will get the first words in each line

```
['this', 'that', 'those', 'bill', 'bob']
```

Comment: I am splitting on space - rather than on comma, but I always like to leave something for the end user to do :)

Answer (score 2):

you can do something using `regex` :

```
>>> import re
>>> b=sum([re.findall(r'^[^,]+(?=,)', i) for i in a], [])
>>> b
['AIG', 'Baylor\xa0College\xa0of\xa0Medicine', 'CGG', 'Citi', 'ExxonMobil', 'Flow-Cal\xa0Inc.', 'Global\xa0Shop\xa0Solutions']
```

Answer (score 1):

> One Line

```
mylist = [line.split(',')[0] for line in yourstring.split('\n')]
```

---

yourstring.split returns a list of all lines and in each line u split it into a list separated by comma and you select the first element in this list.